# Not able to get data from Amazon S3 to EC2 for Training

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I'm new to cloud infrastructure for Deep Learning and trying to use AWS for deep learning first time and I don't know how to access my data from EC2 launched instance.

My data is stored is S3 bucket but I'm not able to find a way how to get it together and start training.

Comment: Could you please clarify your question? Are you running into permissions/credentials problems, or are you asking how to copy data from S3 to EC2? Or are you asking how to reference S3 directly when running Deep Learning training systems?

Comment: I would like to learn how to copy data from S3 to EC2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that EC2 instance. login via ssh.
install aws cli if its not there
configure credentials are add permission for ec2 instance to use s3 bucket.
otherwise add aws secret and access key

get files to your local system
`aws s3 cp s3://mybucket/test.txt test2.txt`

Get files from local to s3
`aws s3 cp test.txt s3://mybucket/test2.txt`

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/cp.html#examples